# Should Put/Call Parity result in Zero Return or the Risk-Free Rate?

Tags: put-call-parity

Sorry in advance if this is a basic question. I'm examining some potential at-the-money put/call arbitrage. What I found surprised me somewhat:

```
            Bid   Ask    Mid
ATM Call = 3.31 x 3.33 (3.32)
ATM Put  = 2.93 x 2.95 (2.94)

Expiration = ~ 1 Month

Underlying Stock Price = 190.00
```

The resulting Put/Call Parity return is equal to:

> (Sell Call, Buy Put, Buy 100 Shares of Underlying)
>
> $(3.32-2.94) \cdot 100 = \$38$
>
> $\dfrac{\$38}{\$190\cdot100} = 0.2\%$
>
> Annualized Return = $0.2\%\cdot12=2.4\%$

This return is very close to the [current stated treasury 'risk-free' rate](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/textview.aspx?data=yield) of 2.48%

I would have expected the return on Put/Call Parity to be zero, however, since the combination of assets is risk-free at that point it would make sense that it pays exactly the risk-free rate.

**Is it expected that I should see this risk-free rate of return or should I be seeing zero return?**

**Is this some other component of return - is this an arbitrage opportunity?**

**Am I merely seeing an algebraically extracted risk free rate from the put call parity formula?**

$C_0+X*e^{-r*t} = P_0+S_0$

$3.32+190*e^{-0.024*(1/12)} = 2.94 + 190 = 192.94$

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: When are the premiums paid?  Also when is the 19000 paid?  Thx

Comment: All at the exact same moment. Theoretically no friction and perfectly liquid.

Comment: Now, or in one month?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Now.

Comment: You are indeed somehow extracting the equity funding cost (which on top of risk-free funding rate could include dividend yield, repo margins) from call put parity.

Comment: @Quantuple I'm looking into equity funding cost and how that might play in here. Thank you for that thought.

Comment: You are welcome just note that the CP parity actually writes $C_0 - P_0 = DF(0,T) ( F(0,T) - S_0 )$ where $F(0,T)$ is the equity forward price (related to equity funding cost) and $DF(0,T)$ the discount factor (related to cash or collateral funding cost)

Comment: $C_0-P_0=DF(0,T)(F(0,T)-K)$

Comment: @AlexC and Quantuple, I interpret your equations to show that there are actually two elements that are contained within the $38 that I am seeing. In this case there are no dividends which, I assume, would mean that I am seeing zero for F(0,T) thereby suggesting all of what I am seeing is from the risk free rate. In some cases, though, if I were to see more than the risk free rate, that would mean there is something contained within the F(0,T) element (or a rare arbitrage opportunity.) I appreciate your efforts here on a question trying to dissect observed results rather than predict outcomes.

Comment: I also verified no arbitrage with $C_0 - P_0 = K_{forward} - K$ as there was a ~$38 difference in the futures market as well. It helped me to understand what I was seeing in the PC parity equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see the risk free rate as the return on the strategy.  That’s because you actually have to invest money , namely usd 19000 minus usd 38, for the one month period.  Hence, there is no arbitrage in the market data you observe.

Comment: I agree that there is no arbitrage, as the formula holds perfectly: 
3.32 + 189.62 = 2.94 + 190  ||
3.32 = 2.94 + .38
I believe you are correct because by paying 19,000 I am essentially __lending__ at the risk free rate. (Easier for me to understand as an arbitrageur would need to pay 38 to __borrow__ the 19,000 if the trade were reversed - Selling Put, Buying Call, Selling Stock.) Thank you for taking the time to answer this question.